# Emacs24 auto-complete error: (void-variable ac-source-c)

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, elisp, emacs24

I tried to install auto-complete and auto-complete-clang-async. When I write something like `std::`, emacs says "auto-complete is not active".

My auto-complete conf is:

```
(require 'auto-complete)
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/elpa/auto-complete/dict")
(set-default 'ac-c-sources
         '(ac-source-abbrev
           ac-source-dictionary
           ac-source-yasnippet
           ac-source-words-in-buffer
           ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers
           ac-source-semantic))
(ac-config-default)
(dolist (m '(c-mode c++-mode java-mode))
(add-to-list 'ac-modes m))
(global-auto-complete-mode t)

;auto-complete-clang-async
(require 'auto-complete-clang-async)

(defun ac-cc-mode-setup ()
  (setq ac-clang-complete-executable "~/.emacs.d/clang-complete")
  (setq ac-sources '(ac-source-clang-async))
  (ac-clang-launch-completion-process)
)

(defun my-ac-config ()
  (add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'ac-cc-mode-setup)
  (add-hook 'auto-complete-mode-hook 'ac-common-setup)
  (global-auto-complete-mode t))
(my-ac-config)
```

The error is:

```
auto-complete error: (void-variable ac-source-c)
```

Comment: After conducting a word search of the source code for `emacs-clang-complete-async` https://github.com/Golevka/emacs-clang-complete-async and `auto-complete` http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/#Source_Code , I see no mention of anything named `ac-source-c`.  The closet matches are `ac-source-css-property` and `ac-source-clang-async`.  An error message of `auto-complete error: (void-variable ac-source-c)` may indicate that the source code has been altered by deleting a portion of the name or putting something like a space or hard return in the middle of the name; or, a byte-comple error?

Comment: Thus, the original poster may wish to search his / her source code for `ac-source-c` to see where the problem lies.

Comment: Add `(setq debug-on-error t)` at the beginning of your ~/.emacs and show us the backtrace which you should hopefully get when you hit that error again.